# Como puedo sumar resultados de una consulta y agrupar su sumatoria a una linea?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ISNULL(fact.nro_docum,rem.nro_docum) AS Documento,p.cod_docum,
    ISNULL(fact.fec_doc,rem.fec_doc) AS Fecha_Documento,
    fact.fec_venc AS Vencimiento,
    v.nro_docum AS Pedido,
    v.cod_tipopedido AS Tipo_de_Pedido,
    v.fec_doc AS Fecha_Pedido,
    v.cod_tit,cli.nom_tit,
    v.cod_negocio,
    fact.cod_fpago,
    facs.cod_articulo,
    facs.cod_negocio,
    facs.monto_imponible,
    fact.imp_tot_mn
    FROM cpt_pedidos(NOLOCK) v 
    INNER JOIN cps_pedidos(NOLOCK) p ON  p.cod_docum IN('credito','ncredito') 
    AND p.cod_doca = v.cod_docum 
    AND p.serie_doca = v.serie_docum 
    AND p.nro_doca = v.nro_docum
    INNER JOIN ct_articulos(NOLOCK) a ON  a.cod_articulo = p.cod_articulo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_facturas(NOLOCK) fact ON  fact.nro_trans = p.nro_trans 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_remitos(NOLOCK) rem ON  rem.nro_trans = p.nro_trans
    INNER JOIN cps_facturas facs on facs.nro_trans=fact.nro_trans and a.cod_articulo=facs.cod_articulo
    INNER JOIN ct_clientes(NOLOCK) cli ON  cli.cod_tit = v.cod_tit
    WHERE v.fec_doc >='20210301' AND v.fec_doc <= '20210331' and    facs.tipo_vta not in('B')
    and ISNULL(fact.nro_docum,rem.nro_docum)='231832' and fact.nro_trans=facs.nro_trans 
    Group by  
        iSNULL(fact.nro_docum,rem.nro_docum),
        p.cod_docum,
        ISNULL(fact.fec_doc,rem.fec_doc), 
        fact.fec_venc,
        v.nro_docum,
        v.cod_tipopedido,
        v.fec_doc,
        v.cod_tit,
        cli.nom_tit,
        v.cod_negocio,
        fact.cod_fpago,
        facs.cod_articulo,
        facs.cod_negocio,
        facs.monto_imponible,
        fact.imp_tot_mn`
```

Comment: Resulta muy complicado contestar preguntas sobre lo que hace un código sin ver ese mismo código. Te sugiero que copies y pegues tu código del SELECT como texto para poder evaluarlo y depurar los posibles errores. Un saludo

Comment: Ok perfecto te paso mi consulta

Comment: Estoy tratando de pegar la consulta pero no estoy pudiendo como puedo hacertela llegara?

Comment: entras en SQL Server, seleccionas el select y lo copias. Luego editas tu pregunta y pegas el select copiado. Para ellos le das en el botón de código de la parte de arriba para que te lo espacíe con 4 espacios. De todas formas por eso no te preocupes, si no te sale como código, alguien te podrá editar la pregunta y formatearla. Un saludo

Comment: Con `sum(<columna a sumar>)` y [`GROUP BY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hola ya probé asi y no funciona, voy a tratar de explicarme mejor

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando esta consulta que replica tu tabla:

```
WITH fakeData AS (
    SELECT 1 AS cod_negocio, 10 AS monto
    UNION SELECT 2, 15
    UNION SELECT 2, 10
    UNION SELECT 3, 5
    UNION SELECT 3, 10
)

cod_negocio monto
1   10
2   10
2   15
3   5
3   10
```

Y realizando el siguiente agrupamiento:

```
SELECT cod_negocio, 
       sum(monto) AS monto 
FROM fakeData
GROUP BY cod_negocio
```

Obtenés el output esperado en ANSI SQL:

```
cod_negocio monto
1   10
2   25
3   15
```

**Actualización**

Teniendo en cuenta la consulta compartida. Podrías utilizar la misma estrategia creando una consulta bloque temporaria como la siguiente:

```
WITH tempQuery as (
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ISNULL(fact.nro_docum,rem.nro_docum) AS Documento,p.cod_docum,
    ISNULL(fact.fec_doc,rem.fec_doc) AS Fecha_Documento,
    fact.fec_venc AS Vencimiento,
    v.nro_docum AS Pedido,
    v.cod_tipopedido AS Tipo_de_Pedido,
    v.fec_doc AS Fecha_Pedido,
    v.cod_tit,
    cli.nom_tit,
    v.cod_negocio,
    fact.cod_fpago,
    facs.cod_articulo,
    facs.cod_negocio,
    facs.monto_imponible,
    fact.imp_tot_mn
    FROM cpt_pedidos(NOLOCK) v 
    INNER JOIN cps_pedidos(NOLOCK) p ON  p.cod_docum IN('credito','ncredito') 
    AND p.cod_doca = v.cod_docum 
    AND p.serie_doca = v.serie_docum 
    AND p.nro_doca = v.nro_docum
    INNER JOIN ct_articulos(NOLOCK) a ON  a.cod_articulo = p.cod_articulo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_facturas(NOLOCK) fact ON  fact.nro_trans = p.nro_trans 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_remitos(NOLOCK) rem ON  rem.nro_trans = p.nro_trans
    INNER JOIN cps_facturas facs on facs.nro_trans=fact.nro_trans and a.cod_articulo=facs.cod_articulo
    INNER JOIN ct_clientes(NOLOCK) cli ON  cli.cod_tit = v.cod_tit
    WHERE v.fec_doc >='20210301' AND v.fec_doc <= '20210331' and    facs.tipo_vta not in('B')
    and ISNULL(fact.nro_docum,rem.nro_docum)='231832' and fact.nro_trans=facs.nro_trans 
    Group by  
        iSNULL(fact.nro_docum,rem.nro_docum),
        p.cod_docum,
        ISNULL(fact.fec_doc,rem.fec_doc), 
        fact.fec_venc,
        v.nro_docum,
        v.cod_tipopedido,
        v.fec_doc,
        v.cod_tit,
        cli.nom_tit,
        v.cod_negocio,
        fact.cod_fpago,
        facs.cod_articulo,
        facs.cod_negocio,
        facs.monto_imponible,
        fact.imp_tot_mn`
)

SELECT cod_negocio, 
       sum(monto_imponible) AS monto 
FROM tempQuery
GROUP BY cod_negocio
```

Comment: Ok entiendo pero ahi vos estas sabiendo los resultados el tema es que yo no se que resultados voy a obtener no se si me explico?

Comment: Disculpa, no te estoy entendiendo.

Comment: primero muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo, pero veo que el UNION que haces en el select es con los datos ya vistos para que sume y agrupe, es así o tal vez estoy interpretando mal?

Comment: Lo que no puedo llegar a entender es ¿Cómo son tus datos de origen? ¿Salen de diferentes tablas? ¿Cómo son sus relaciones? tal vez si agregás eso en tu consulta original tengamos más herramientas para ayudarte.

Comment: Hola si claro te enteindo, salen de muchas tablas, pegue la consulta para que la vean no se si se puede ver? soy nuevo en este foro y todavia no agarre la mecanica, en esa consulta se pueden ver todas las tablas que hay involucradas y el resultado es un detalle de la Factura, que tiene diferentes negocios lo que quiero es agrupar esos negocios y que me de un solo resultado con la suma de los precios, no se si me explique bien

Comment: Ahí actualicé teniendo en cuenta tu consulta inicial. Deberías poner el input y output esperado para mayor ayuda. Porque ahora tu pregunta quedo sólo como una consulta y es posible que la pregunta sea cerrada por falta de contexto.

Comment: Ahh ok disculpen y gracias por editar ahora les agrego el Output

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deseas en base de datos se conoce como 'función de agregación', consiste en aplicar una función a una agrupación de datos (en datos tabulares, agrupas filas y puedes sumar, sacar promedio, el valor más alto, el primer valor... etc. de la agrupación).

Ejemplo en pandas:

```py
#%%
import pandas as pd
#%%
df=pd.DataFrame({'Cod_negocio':[1,2,2,3,3],'Monto':[10,15,10,5,10]})
# %%
resultado=df.groupby('Cod_negocio').sum()
# %%
print(resultado)
```

output:

```
             Monto
Cod_negocio
1               10
2               25
3               15
```

Ejemplo en SQL [Click aquí para probar query](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby_orderby):

```sql
SELECT SUM(CustomerID),*
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY SUM(CustomerID) DESC;
```

Comment: Interesante esa no la conocia me gustaría pasarte mi consulta para que la veas pero si el output que busco es ese mismo